# Why can't I reference the attr `android:popupEnterTransition`?

Tags: android

Starting from API 23, the [default Spinner style](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-release/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml#758) has `android:popupEnterTransition` and `android:popupExitTransition` set:

```
<style name="Widget.Material.Spinner" parent="Widget.Spinner.DropDown">
    [...]
    <item name="popupEnterTransition">@transition/popup_window_enter</item>
    <item name="popupExitTransition">@transition/popup_window_exit</item>
    [...]
</style>
```

I'm trying to override these in my sub-style, but it won't compile (even though I'm compiling against API 23):

```
<style name="Spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Spinner">
    <item name="android:popupEnterTransition">@null</item>
</style>
```

I'm getting `Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:popupEnterTransition'`.

Why is this not available?  It's right there in the [framework attrs.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#4491).

Was this left out by mistake?  I can't imagine why this would be intended to be private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`popupEnterTransition`, despite being in the *framework* attributes, is not in the *Android SDK's* [list of attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html), therefore making it a private attribute you cannot set in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But why is it private? The other PopupWindow attr and styleable values are available. The new Spinner transitions in 23 are making my app feel slow, so I'm trying to remove them without resorting to something awful like reflection. :)

Comment: No idea. You could put in a feature request at [b.android.com](http://b.android.com) if you'd like them to be public.